# NextJS: Dynamic layout for logged in and logged out pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating away from a React app with react-router-dom to NextJS, mainly for pre-rendering for SEO meta tags.

I don't seem to be able to render different layouts based on if I'm logged in or not. I understand that Next and static generated pages are different in concept, but I feel like this must be a very common pattern anyway?

My app:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

And the Layout:

```
export const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSession()

  const LayoutComponent = isAuthenticated ? PrivateLayout : PublicLayout

  return <LayoutComponent>{children}</LayoutComponent>
}
```

Obviously this would work fine in a normal React app, but not here.

If I `console.log` inside `PrivateLayout` and `PublicLayout`, the NextJS dev terminal would log something (A), and Chrome dev tool would log something (B). It's because `isAuthenticated` is using localstorage to determine if I'm logged in or not.

How could this be solved?

PS. This would work if I start logged out, and log in. Then the layout changes. But not if I reload the page. I'm still authenticated in the browser, but Next gives me the logged out layout.

Comment: If you're handling authentication on the client-side (based off `localStorage`) then there's no way around it. You'd have to move authentication to the server so what's render on the server matches what gets rendered on the client during hydration.